# Text to .xls With Formatting

Tags: excel, formatting

Is there a way to write out in a text editor format cell a1 bold and set the contents of that cell and then save the file in .xls or any excel format? I also need to set the color of the font as well or the background color of the cell.

I feel like this is a bit of a long shot but for a very odd reason I need to be able to do this manually.

Comment: You can save a text file containing an HTML table, and give it an .xls file extension.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here. What is a "text editor format cell a1 bold"? "Is there a way" also isn't an acceptable question here, because an answer of "Yes, there is a way" or "No, there is not a way" with no other information would be a valid answer. Please [edit] your question to be more specific about what you're trying to do, so we can try and help you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

`<table><tr><td style="background-color:#0F0"><font color="red"><b>42</b></font></td></tr></table>`

Saved as "test.xls" will open in Excel (but there will be a security prompt becuase the file contents don't match a "native" xls file format)